# jQuery reduce number of listeners/events

Tags: jquery

the below code works for me but I need it cleaned up and simplified as much as possible, can anyone help? Thanks in advance

```
$('#dealTemplateI18nMetaTitle_en_AU').keyup( function() {
   var len = $(this).val().length;
   if (len >= 32) {
     $('#dealTemplateI18nMetaTitle_en_AU').css("background-color", "#ff3b3b").css("font-size", "16px").css("font-weight", "bold").css("color", "#ffffff");
   } else {
     $('#dealTemplateI18nMetaTitle_en_AU').css("background-color", "#82b548").css("font-size", "16px").css("font-weight", "bold").css("color", "#ffffff");
   }
});
```

Comment: Did you try to remove the obvious redundancies? The only thing that changes inside the `if` is the color, so move the conditional in there using the `?:` operator. Also, you 'd be much better off by setting a class on the element rather than brute forcing CSS attributes on it.

Comment: "Here's my code, make it easier to read"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can remove any listeners or events (you only have one and its the one you need if you're watching for keyup events). If I were going make changes to the js without changing the markup, I'd go with something like this:
http://jsfiddle.net/mrYGA/

```
$("#dealTemplateI18nMetaTitle_en_AU").keyup(function() {
    var el = $(this);
    var len = el.val().length;
    var bgcolor = len >= 32 ? "#ff3b3b" : "#82b548";

    el.css({
        "font-size": "16px",
        "font-weight": "bold",
        "color": "#ffffff",
        "background-color": bgcolor
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks to everyone, is it possible that I can have this run on page load (to do an initial character count) and then also on keyups?

Comment: Check this fiddle .. http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/KFDZN/

Comment: Hey Sushanth, doesn't work on page load? Just on keyup

Answer (score 1):

You can use **class** here instead and **cache your selector..**

```
var $elem = $('#dealTemplateI18nMetaTitle_en_AU');
$elem.addClass('large');
$elem.keyup(function () {
    (this.value.length) >= 32 ? $elem.addClass('error') 
                              : $elem.removeClas('error');
});

.large {
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color:#ffffff;
    background-color: #82b548;
}
.error {
    background-color:#ff3b3b;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

How about moving styles to a class and change the class.

http://jsfiddle.net/chamikasandamal/LzZMs/

```
$('#dealTemplateI18nMetaTitle_en_AU').keyup(function () {
    var len = $(this).val().length;
    if (len >= 32) {
        $('#dealTemplateI18nMetaTitle_en_AU').addClass("error");
        $('#dealTemplateI18nMetaTitle_en_AU').removeClass("no-error");
    } else {
        $('#dealTemplateI18nMetaTitle_en_AU').removeClass("error");
        $('#dealTemplateI18nMetaTitle_en_AU').addClass("no-error");
    }
});
```

CSS,

```
#dealTemplateI18nMetaTitle_en_AU {
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight:bold;
    color:#fff;
}
#dealTemplateI18nMetaTitle_en_AU.error {
    background-color:#ff3b3b;
}
#dealTemplateI18nMetaTitle_en_AU.no-error {
    background-color:#82b548;
}
```